# Cannot GET /posts/whatever . It looks like req.params is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am newbie at this, so sorry for some silly mistakes. Happy to learn. Whenever I use URL : localhost:3000/posts/whatever I get a cannot GET error. Before you ask, yes that is after I put content in posts page. It looks like there is some problem with `req`.

This is my code:

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const _ =require("loadash");

const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing.";
const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

let posts = [];

app.get("/", function(req,res){
  res.render("home", {
    startingContent: homeStartingContent,
    posts:posts
  });
});

app.get("/contact",function(req,res){
  res.render("contact",{contactContent: contactContent});
});

app.get("/about",function(req,res){
  res.render("about",{aboutContent: aboutContent});
});

app.get("/compose",function(req,res){
  res.render("compose");
});

app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
  const post = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  };

  posts.push(post);

  res.redirect("/");

});

app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res){
  const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);
  posts.forEach(function(post){
      const storedTitle = _.lowerCase(post.title);

      if(storedTitle === requestedTitle){
        res.render("post",{
            title:post.title,
            content:post.content,
        });
      }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Which method u r calling?? GET or POST???

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question

Comment: Show exactly what calls are you making with all details, and what responses you get from each.

Comment: Remaining routing (url) is working fine? I mean /contact?

Comment: Remaining all routes are working fine.

Comment: put a res.send('hello');  before requestedTitle and it will give an output

Comment: may be your posts array is empty and loop is not executing and at the end no response is send to client side

Comment: No I am logging posts array in my terminal and it is printing fine. res.send also not working.

Comment: are you sure this condition  ( `if(storedTitle === requestedTitle)`  ) is passing ?
if not you have to to have a default res.render() or res.send() at the end of loop

Comment: I deleted everything in that "app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res)" and just tried to print 'req.params.postName' . It's not working.

Comment: This is due to the async nature of the foreach. Do a normal loop and should work :)

Comment: app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params.postName);
});   I did simply this now. What's going on! Not working.

Comment: are you calling the url  in browser in this way ?

http://localhost:3102/posts?sasa

Comment: localhost:3000/posts/anything

Comment: Some incompatibility between versions of node / express? What versions are you on?

Comment: I guess not because every other routes are working fine.Node : v10.16.3,

Comment: console.log(req); - see what it gives back - it will be huge. Try and narrow it down. maybe even console.log(req.params) :)

Comment: I did console.log(req); in "app.get("/", function(req,res)". But it logged nothing.

Comment: Please console.log(req) in  app.get("/posts/:postName")

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar it says cannot GET /posts/whatItyped

Comment: Just add this app.use(bodyParser.json()); and it will work. I have tried it but don`t know the reason why it worked.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth - The bodyParser middleware has nothing at all to do with a GET request which appears to be the subject of this question. That's used for a POST or a PUT where there is a request body to read and parse.  Please don't suggest things that you don't understand why they might actually be a solution to the problem.  A lot of bad code has been written by people guessing how to solve problems rather than actually understanding the problem and a solid solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you'll have to correct `lodash` from `loadash` in the require section.

Also I do believe it's your middelware that's a problem.

I added a bunch of log lines to see how your code is manipulated.

This is the compose function:

```
app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
  console.log('(BODY) compose variables: ', req.body.postTitle, req.body.postBody)
  console.log('(PARAMS) compose variables: ', req.params.postTitle, req.params.postBody)
  console.log('(QUERY) compose variables: ', req.query.postTitle, req.query.postBody)
  const post = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  };
  console.log('compose variables as object', post)
  posts.push(post);
  console.log('object pushed to array', posts)
  res.redirect("/");

});
```

And this is the `GET /posts/:postTitle` function.

```
app.get("/posts/:postName", function(req, res){
  const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);
  console.log('requestedTitle: ', requestedTitle)
  console.log('Array to loop: ', posts)
  posts.forEach(function(post){
      console.log('current looped object: ', post)
      const storedTitle = _.lowerCase(post.title);
      console.log('looped title: ', post.title)
      console.log('storedtitle: ', storedTitle)

      if(storedTitle === requestedTitle){
        res.render("post",{
            title:post.title,
            content:post.content,
        });
      }
  });
});
```

These log lines showed me that everything works just fine if I compose the right `POST` request in Postman.

`POST http://localhost:3000/compose`
Body: `x-www-form-urlencoded, postTitle: test, postBody: testbody`

If you're sending your information in the `POST` request other than urlencoded you'll have to load the bodyParser middelware that matches.

If I send data as params (URL) or normal form data it populates the `posts` array with empty objects.

---

Log lines with correct Postman settings:
`POST /compose`

> (BODY) compose variables:  test
>   (PARAMS) compose variables:  undefined undefined
>   (QUERY) compose variables:  undefined undefined
>   compose variables as object { title: 'test', content: '' }
>   object pushed to array [ { title: 'test', content: '' } ]

`GET /posts/test`

> requestedTitle:  test
>   Array to loop:  [ { title: 'test', content: '' } ]
>   current looped object:  { title: 'test', content: '' }
>   looped title:  test
>   storedtitle:  test

---

Log lines with form-data
`POST /compose`

> (BODY) compose variables:  undefined undefined
>   (PARAMS) compose variables:  undefined undefined
>   (QUERY) compose variables:  undefined undefined
>   compose variables as object { title: undefined, content: undefined }
>   object pushed to array [ { title: undefined, content: undefined } ]

`GET /posts/test`

> requestedTitle:  test
>   Array to loop:  [ { title: undefined, content: undefined } ]
>   current looped object:  { title: undefined, content: undefined }
>   looped title:  undefined
>   storedtitle:

---

And log lines with data as params (URL data)

`POST /compose?postTitle=test&postBody=testbody`

> (BODY) compose variables:  undefined undefined
>   (PARAMS) compose variables:  undefined undefined
>   (QUERY) compose variables:  test testbody
>   compose variables as object { title: undefined, content: undefined }
>   object pushed to array [ { title: undefined, content: undefined } ]

`GET /posts/test`

> requestedTitle:  test
>   Array to loop:  [ { title: undefined, content: undefined } ]
>   current looped object:  { title: undefined, content: undefined }
>   looped title:  undefined
>   storedtitle:

---

So you should find out what data comes into your application and make sure you have the correct middleware loaded.